# cocoapods installation error in xcode

Tags: cocoapods

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

`/usr/local/bin/pod install`

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

`CocoaPods : 1.4.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
    RubyGems : 2.0.14.1
        Host : Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
       Xcode : 7.3.1 (7D1014)
         Git : git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories :`

#### Plugins

`cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0`

#### Podfile

`ruby
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'Maps_Google' do
pod 'GoogleMaps'
end`

#### Error

`` LoadError - cannot load such file -- nanaimo
/Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.4/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:23:in `read_from_path'
/Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:200:in `initialize_from_file'
/Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:102:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:907:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:906:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:906:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:901:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:75:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:154:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:153:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
/Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' ``

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=cannot+load+such+file+--+nanaimo&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:921:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:921:in`block in connect'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:921:in`connect'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in`start'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1373:in `request'
    from /Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:72:in`get_api_results'
    from /Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:26:in `search'
    from /Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/inspector.rb:65:in`search_query'
    from /Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/inspector.rb:59:in `search_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:119:in`search_for_exceptions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:67:in `report_error'
    from /Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in`handle_exception'
    from /Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Users/aliapple/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:325:in`run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0/bin/pod:55:in`'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in`'
aliapples-MacBook-Pro:Maps_Google aliapple$

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem is happened with Xcode9.3 , i was try to instantiate pod by xcode9.3 , same issues appeared.**

*Just i am sharing with you how to resolved my issues. create project by xcode 9.1 or 9.2 , and instantiate pod whatever you want than open project by Xcode 9.3 *

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with nanimo too in 'pod install' command.

For me solved uninstall cocoapods and nanimo globally. I put the answer in an issue of cocapods repo:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7566

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is problem with the version of cocoa pod for as we were using version 1.8.4 but after using command

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

from link:
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started

worked out and it is currently working fine.