# Cocoapods can't install

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to install podfile in my project through terminal. I am facing below error :

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: It's a private repository? Are you allowed to fetch it? SSHKey? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: **I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50022321/3475875) will help you**

Comment: Share a source path for remote location.

Comment: Actually I am working with Xcode 9.2 only.

Comment: I am not working with any repository. I simply created project in Xcode 9.2 and trying to add podfile init.

Comment: try 
pod deintegrate
pod install

Comment: show your podfile

Comment: @thorb65 please check my edited question with attachment.

Comment: There's no pod specified in the screen cap you've posted.

Comment: actually I don't want to install any pod. I just want to make setup for cocoapods, which gives me above error.

Comment: try inserting this in the first line: `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your cocoapod as root?
Maybe removing ~/.cocoapods/repos/master and then pod setup solve your problem.

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master

pod setup
```